# Office 365 groups 'files' portion with the 'email attachments' folder

Tags: office-365, groups, incoming-email

Question about groups I hope it is still considered sharepoint related.

Inside the group there is the section 'files'. Inside Files, there is a default folder called 'email attachments'. I was wondering what is the need for this folder, since any incoming email to the group (which is built around a mailing list) does not deposit the attachment in this folder (as the name would led you to believe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In addition, you can edit files sent as email attachments to the group, send a reply to the group and store a copy in SharePoint to maintain version control going forward. When you click Edit and reply, the file is automatically added to a new folder in the SharePoint document library called Email attachments, creating a single version for the file, enabling co-authoring for the group and making it very easy to track changes."

https://blogs.office.com/2016/11/17/introducing-a-new-file-experience-for-groups-in-outlook-on-the-web/